# Gmetad sees one host per cluster instead of many

Tags: ganglia

I'm trying to configure Ganglia 3.6.
I have 8 machines, grouped in to 4 clusters. On one machine I run gmetad, that should collect statistics from all clusters:

```
#fragment of gmetad.conf
data_source "A cluster" 10 A.com:8649
data_source "B cluster" 10 B1.com:8649 B2.com:8650 B3.com:8652
data_source "C cluster" 10 C1:8649     C2.8650
data_source "D cluster" 10 D1.com:8649 D2.com:8650
```

All nodes run gmond configured to use unicast, each on the port as configured above. The problem is that I see each cluster as having a single machine ("1 host up") that is called `localhost.localdomain` instead of for example three machines in case of cluster `B cluster`. It is the same when I inspect ganglia-web, rrds folder and gmetad XML obtained via telnet.

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong? I thought configuring different ports for unicast will be enough. I cannot use multicast because of network security policies.